# Mean of repeated columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with repeated column names which account for repeated measurements.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': randn(5), 'B': randn(5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': randn(5), 'B': randn(5)})
df3 = pd.concat([df,df2], axis=1)
df3
      A         B         A         B
0 -0.875884 -0.298203  0.877414  1.282025
1  1.605602 -0.127038 -0.286237  0.572269
2  1.349540 -0.067487  0.126440  1.063988
3 -0.142809  1.282968  0.941925 -1.593592
4 -0.630353  1.888605 -1.176436 -1.623352
```

I'd like to take the mean of cols 'A's and 'B's such that the dataframe shrinks to

```
      A         B    
0  0.000765  0.491911
1  0.659682  0.222616
2  0.737990  0.498251
3  0.399558 -0.155312
4 -0.903395  0.132627
```

If I do the typical

```
df3['A'].mean(axis=1)
```

I get a Series (with no column name) and I should then build a new dataframe with the means of each col group. Also the .groupby() method apparently doesn't allow you to group by column name, but rather you give the columns and it sorts the indexes. Is there a fancy way to do this?

*Side question: why does*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': randn(5), 'B': randn(5), 'A': randn(5), 'B': randn(5)})
```

*not generate a 4-column dataframe but merges same-name cols?*

Comment: To answer your side question, why do you think defining a dict with duplicate keys would work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `level` keyword (regarding your columns as the first level (level 0) of the index with only one level in this case):

```
In [11]: df3
Out[11]:
          A         B         A         B
0 -0.367326 -0.422332  2.379907  1.502237
1 -1.060848  0.083976  0.619213 -0.303383
2  0.805418 -0.109793  0.257343  0.186462
3  2.419282 -0.452402  0.702167  0.216165
4 -0.464248 -0.980507  0.823302  0.900429

In [12]: df3.mean(axis=1, level=0)
Out[12]:
          A         B
0  1.006291  0.539952
1 -0.220818 -0.109704
2  0.531380  0.038334
3  1.560725 -0.118118
4  0.179527 -0.040039
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created df3 in a strange way for this simple case the following would work:

```
In [86]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': randn(5), 'B': randn(5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': randn(5), 'B': randn(5)})
print(df)
print(df2)

          A         B
0 -0.732807 -0.571942
1 -1.546377 -1.586371
2  0.638258  0.569980
3 -1.017427  1.395300
4  0.666853 -0.258473

[5 rows x 2 columns]
          A         B
0  0.589185  1.029062
1 -1.447809 -0.616584
2 -0.506545  0.432412
3 -1.168424  0.312796
4  1.390517  1.074129

[5 rows x 2 columns]
In [87]:

(df+df2)/2
Out[87]:
          A         B
0 -0.071811  0.228560
1 -1.497093 -1.101477
2  0.065857  0.501196
3 -1.092925  0.854048
4  1.028685  0.407828

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

to answer your side question, this is nothing to do with Pandas and more to do with the dict constructor:

```
In [88]:

{'A': randn(5), 'B': randn(5), 'A': randn(5), 'B': randn(5)}
Out[88]:
{'B': array([-0.03087831, -0.24416885, -2.29924624,  0.68849978,  0.41938536]),
 'A': array([ 2.18471335,  0.68051101, -0.35759988,  0.54023489,  0.49029071])}
```

dict keys must be unique so my guess is that in the constructor it just reassigns the values to the pre-existing keys

**EDIT**

If you insist on having duplicate columns then you have to create a new dataframe from this because if you were to update the columns 'A' and 'B', the mean will be duplicated still as the columns are repeated:

```
In [92]:

df3 = pd.concat([df,df2], axis=1)
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df['A'], new_df['B'] = df3['A'].sum(axis=1)/df3['A'].shape[1], df3['B'].sum(axis=1)/df3['B'].shape[1]
new_df
Out[92]:
          A         B
0 -0.071811  0.228560
1 -1.497093 -1.101477
2  0.065857  0.501196
3 -1.092925  0.854048
4  1.028685  0.407828

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

So the above would work with df3 and in fact for an arbritary numer of repeated columns which is why I am using shape, you could hard code this to 2 if you new the columns were only ever duplicated once

Comment: I created it this way so that I can have a df with duplicate cols, which is what I actually have. So the question is how to manage it with an already given df that has duplicate cols. As for the side question, thanks, now I understand.

Comment: @gmask I've added an additional solution, essentially you have to create a new dataframe in order to not have the columns repeated